# Wiring from Oven to Switch

Tags: electrical, kitchens, oven

[image: Wiring Layout]

At the moment under the oven switch the cable is plastered over (without capping) till it reaches under the counter; there it pops out of the raw plaster and is draped across the back of the units to the double-oven housing where its just wired into the back of the oven.

My sparky suggested channeling out the wall (light blue line) down and across, then capping it. But I was wondering if it was better, or if theres any reason not to channel straight down to the floor boards, then tac the cable to the joist across the width of  the kitchen before coming up (channeling again) to the cooker connection point (as in the purple line).

The blue line would be 70cm high; total length of cable travel 150cm 
And this is in the UK.

Comment: What is the actual question you're asking? Does it relate to electricals or laying wire across a wall?

Comment: @alt It was relating to the path the wiring could/should take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some places it is illegal to run hidden power cables horizontally across walls unless they are within a specific short distance from floor or ceiling.

For example, in the UK I believe all power cables to/from a mid-wall switch must run vertically to or until near the floor/ceiling.

So, the answer may depend where you live.

---

[image]

Reference: [IET cables in walls](http://electrical.theiet.org/wiring-matters/27/cables-in-wall.cfm?type=pdf)

Comment: Updated with lengths. The blue line would be 70cm high (from floor); total length of cable travel 150cm (horizontal). And UK based, the land of Part-P headaches and restricted zones

Comment: @Chris: See reference above. It's complicated but I think you need to route in the other direction, up across down.

Comment: http://www.ultimatehandyman.co.uk/WIRE%20IN%20JOISTS.jpg the safe zones "permitted routes" afaik relate to cables unprotected (no trunking/conduit) and near the surface. We had a plug socket added by an electrician for the hob ign which goes down and dog legs to the left. Exceeding max travel and having a huge channel the length of the wall is a worry. Joist seems less (bar floorboard removal)